# Outer Div not Expanding to Inner Div

Tags: html, css

So I have checked nearly every example on SO, and none seem to fix my problem, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? All I'm trying to do is have a div within another div, and have text in that on one line (not wordwrap). The problem is that the outer div doesn't expand properly to the inner div.

**Example Code:**

```
<style>
    .container {
        left: 10%; 
        border: 0.2vw dashed black; 
        padding: 3%; 
        position: fixed;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .textbox {
        font-size: 800%; 
        padding: 10%; 
        border: 0.2vw solid red;  
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="textbox" >
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It does expand to the child's size but you've put extra padding on it so it becomes bigger.

Comment: If it doesn't fit because of the inner padding, doesnt it mean that its not expanding?

Comment: Okay, I guess with expanding you meant to 'push away' or create empty space rather than adapting to the size of the child element...

Comment: See image above (edited) for what I mean.

Comment: The `white-space: nowrap;` is what's killing you.  You're fine until the width of the text exceeds the containing div.  It's hard to give you a better solution without knowing a bit more of the context of what you're trying to achieve (the bigger issue would seem to be having text that you don't want wrapped, at the expense of having text off screen).

Answer (score 0):

Word-break was the answer instead of whitespace!

```
.container {
    left: 10%; 
    border: 0.2vw dashed black; 
    padding: 3%; 
    position: fixed;
    word-break:break-all;
}

.textbox {
    font-size: 200%; 
    padding: inherit;
    border: 0.2vw solid red;  
    display: inline-block;
}
```